# Regular expression for a path directory

Tags: regex

I need a regular expression for extracting a JAR name and a version. The input values are in the below format:

```
C:\WORK\Modify file\test2\lib\messageclass-12.jar
C:\WORK\Modify file\test2\lib\utilities-396.jar
C:\WORK\Modify file\test2679\lib\castor-1.jar
```

output should be:

```
messageclass
12

utilities
396

castor
1
```

Any help is appreciated.
**Update**

I am using this in a ant script to extract in 2 properties the values: messageclass and 12 as bellow:

```
<propertyregex override="yes" property="propA" input="@{file}" regexp="here should be the regex" replace="" global="true" />
```

and @{file} is infact  C:\WORK\Modify file\test2\lib\messageclass-12.jar

A sample example can be found on: http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/tasks/tasks/for.html

Final solution based on your suggestions is:

```
            <!-- calculate jar name -->
            <propertyregex override="yes" property="jarname" input="@{file}" regexp="-(\d*)\.jar" replace="" global="true"/>
            <propertyregex override="yes" property="jarname" input="${jarname}" regexp=".*\\(\S*)\\" replace="" global="true"/>
            <!-- calculate jar version -->
            <propertyregex override="yes" property="jarversion" input="@{file}" regexp=".*\\(\S*)-" replace="" global="true"/>
            <propertyregex override="yes" property="jarversion" input="${jarversion}" regexp=".jar" replace="" global="true"/>
```

Comment: What language are you using? It might be better to use some kind of `Path.Split` type function to get the filename, then just split on `-` with a string function (or use regex at that point if you really want to ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.*\\(\S*)-(\d*)\.jar
```

This should do the job.

Comment: If your jar file's name has spaces my regex won't work. @detunized 's regex seems better therefor. But if the jar file doesn't have a version number like C:\WORK\Modify file\test2679\lib\castor-.jar
that regex wouldn't work either. So the best regex would be .*\\(.*)-(\d*)\.jar in my opinion

Comment: Perfect, my final solution based on your suggestion is now posted in the question.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
/.*\\(.*)-(\d+)\.jar/
```

Capture 1 would have the name, and capture 2 the version number.

This example on [Rubular](http://rubular.com/r/9U8dyWAdBr).

Comment: I would change the .* for the name part into \w+ and add a $ so the matching starts from the end: /.*\\(\w+)-(\d+)\.jar$/